# Global convergence for Newton's method in one dimension

Tags: reference-request, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for a Theorem that I can cite which proves that Newton's method for finding a zero of a function converges globally and quadratically if the function $f : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing and convex and has a zero $r \in [a,b]$ with $f(r) = 0$ and $f'(r) \neq 0$, with starting point $x_0 \geq r$. I couldn't find a formal Theorem in any book I have and also not online.

It probably isn't too hard to prove, but due to space restrictions I would like to cite an existing result and I would like to avoid writing "it is a well-known result..." or "it can be easily shown that...".

Comment: Dear @yon: Do you mean Newton's method for finding a zero of the function or Newton's method to find an extremum of the function?

Comment: Finding a zero of the function, I addded it to the original post.

Comment: Then I believe that the two tags concerning optimization should be removed and replaced with the tag 'na.numerical-analysis'. Also, you may want to add the tag 'reference-request'.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: isn't this answered here? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148894

Comment: Theoretically yes, but the paper in the answer there proves a stronger result and is a bit "overkill". I was looking for a simple theorem in a standard book on numerical methods.

Comment: Most textbooks on Numerical Analysis have it. Check e.g. those listed in the References of the wiki article (I fear nobody here is going to do it for you) 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#References

Comment: I will check my university's library tomorrow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prof is so simple that it will not add much to the length of the paper:
Let $F(x)=x-F(x)/F'(x)$, $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$. By convexity, all $x_n>r$, so $F(x_n)>0$,
so $x_n$ is a bounded decreasing sequence, so it has a limit. This limit must be $r$.

Comment: Thank you. I guess putting a short proof will be my last option if I don't find this theorem.

Comment: I checked a standard textbook, Berezin, Zhidkov, Methods of computation, volume 2. They do not state this as a theorem, and say: "as seen from the picture, the sequence is monotone... etc.".

Comment: @mathmath8128:  While your suggested edits add some new ideas to this Answer, that's not really a suitable use for suggested edits.  You might want to provide them as Comments, or if you feel this five year old Accepted Answer is not adequate, it is still allowed for you to post your own Answer.

Comment: @hardmath sure, sounds good. The edit included fixing a typo in the definition of $F$.

Answer (score 2):

*Numerical analysis: Mathematics of scientific computing* by Kincaid and Cheney has a [proof](http://books.google.com/books?id=x69Q226WR8kC&pg=PA86) on page 86 (third edition) if you really need a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The global theorem your are asking for, i.e., monotone convergence for increasing convex functions with a zero, generalizes to the $n$-dimensional case and can be found as Theorem 13.3.7., p. 453, in J.M. Ortega and W.C. Rheinboldt, *Iterative Solution of Nonlinear Equations in Several Variables*, Academic Press, 1970. By the local results, the iterates will eventually converge quadratically.

Answer (score -1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

> - $\ds{x_{n + 1} = x_{n} - {\fermi\pars{x_{n}} \over \fermi'\pars{x_{n}}}.\quad}$ ( *Newton-Rapson* )
> - Define $\ds{\epsilon_{n} \equiv x_{n} - s}$ where $\ds{s}$ is a
>     *root* of $\ds{\fermi\pars{x} = 0}$.
> - We consider a situation where $\ds{\verts{\epsilon_{n}}}$ is *'close'* to $\ds{s}$:

\begin{align}
\epsilon_{n + 1}
&=
\epsilon_{n}
-
{\fermi\pars{s + \epsilon_{n}} \over \fermi'\pars{s + \epsilon_{n}}}
\approx
\epsilon_{n}
-
{\overbrace{\fermi\pars{s}}^{\ds{=\ 0}} + \fermi'\pars{s}\epsilon_{n} + \fermi''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{2}/2
 \over
 \fermi'\pars{s} + \fermi''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}
 + \fermi'''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{2}/2}
\\[3mm]&=
{\fermi''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{2}/2 + \fermi'''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{3}/2
 \over
 \fermi'\pars{s} + \fermi''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}
 + \fermi'''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{2}/2}
=
{\fermi''\pars{s}/2 + \fermi'''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}/2
 \over
 \fermi'\pars{s} + \fermi''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}
 + \fermi'''\pars{s}\epsilon_{n}^{2}/2}\,\epsilon_{n}^{2}
\end{align}

Up to second order in $\epsilon_{n}$, the last expression is reduced to:
$$
\bbox[15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\epsilon_{n + 1} \approx
\half\,{\fermi''\pars{s} \over \fermi'\pars{s}}\,\epsilon_{n}^{2}}}
$$
That is the reason we usually say that "$\tt\mbox{Newton-Rapson converges quadratically}$".